# How to show multi-line GCM push notifications in Delphi?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, notifications, push

Using Berlin/Tokyo and Kinvey, when receiving a GCM push notification containing a long message text, only one line is displayed, and the remaining text is cut out.

Digging the internet, it seems that for those notifications to be displayed in full length, there is need to set BigContentView, but Delphi does not expose it.

Does anyone knows how to handle this, so notifications will be show in full length?

Answer (score 0):

You have one 2 choice :

Hack the unit System.Android.Notification.pas / System.Notification.pas to add the function you need. It's easy, just one function need to be updated, this one :

```
function TNotificationCenterAndroid.CreateNativeNotification(const ANotification: TNotification): JNotification;

  function GetDefaultNotificationSound: Jnet_Uri;
  begin
    Result := TJRingtoneManager.JavaClass.getDefaultUri(TJRingtoneManager.JavaClass.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
  end;

  function GetDefaultIconID: Integer;
  begin
    Result := TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationInfo.icon;
  end;

  function GetDefaultIcon: JBitmap;
  begin
    Result := TJBitmapFactory.JavaClass.decodeResource(TAndroidHelper.Context.getResources(), GetDefaultIconID);
  end;

  function GetContentTitle: JCharSequence;
  begin
    if ANotification.Title.IsEmpty then
      Result := StrToJCharSequence(TAndroidHelper.ApplicationTitle)
    else
      Result := StrToJCharSequence(ANotification.Title);
  end;

  function GetContentText: JCharSequence;
  begin
    Result := StrToJCharSequence(ANotification.AlertBody);
  end;

  function GetContentIntent: JPendingIntent;
  var
    Intent: JIntent;
  begin
    Intent := TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName());
    Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    SaveNotificationIntoIntent(Intent, ANotification);
    Result := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(TAndroidHelper.Context, TGeneratorUniqueID.GenerateID, Intent, TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  end;

var
  NotificationBuilder: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
begin
  NotificationBuilder := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setDefaults(TJNotification.JavaClass.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
  if ANotification.SmallIconId <> 0 then NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(ANotification.SmallIconId)
  else NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(GetDefaultIconID);
  if ANotification.largeIconObj <> nil then NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(ANotification.largeIconObj);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setContentTitle(GetContentTitle);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setContentText(GetContentText);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setTicker(GetContentText);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(GetContentIntent);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setNumber(ANotification.Number);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(True);
  NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setWhen(TJDate.Create.getTime);
  if (ANotification.Color <> TalphaColorRec.null) and
     (TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT >= 21) then NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setColor(ANotification.Color);
  if ANotification.VibratePattern <> nil then NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setVibrate(ANotification.VibratePattern);

  if ANotification.EnableSound then
    if ANotification.SoundName.IsEmpty then
      NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setSound(GetDefaultNotificationSound)
    else
      NotificationBuilder := NotificationBuilder.setSound(StrToJURI(ANotification.SoundName));

  // Action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1!!!
  // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction
  Result := NotificationBuilder.Build;
end;
```

Or second variant, avoid the use of delphi TnotificationCenter and build your own from scratch

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The hack seems to not be so simple, since there is no BigTextStyle defined. This is my first mobile app, so I will need to figure out how I would implement it.